# sync folder not working vagrant ionicbox

Tags: ionic-framework, vagrant, virtualbox

folders are not getting synced

q1: where should i clone my project ? in host or guestmachine so that sync works.

q2: vagrant up doesnt show shared folder mouted.

vagrantfile:
`config.vm.synced_folder "ionic-projects/", "/home/vagrant/ionic-projects"`

vagrant up

==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    default: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    default: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    default: capable.

==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...

==> default: Checking if box 'drifty/ionic-android' is up to date...

==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...

```
default: Adapter 1: nat
```

==> default: Forwarding ports...

```
default: 8100 (guest) => 8100 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 35729 (guest) => 35729 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

default: SSH username: vagrant
```

**EDIT**: had a private key issue now the shared folders are mouted .
but still sync fails

==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...

==> default: Setting hostname...

==> default: Mounting shared folders...

```
default: /vagrant => /home/nithin/Documents/Kappian/app
```

==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`

==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

Comment: is there any permission issues for sync folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was with private key

1.setting these in vagrant file will resolve auto mount issue of shared folders.
username:vagrant
password:vagrant

auth method will be changed to password.

2.see that proper permission is given for the shared folder.